# Fix intercolumn whitespace in tabular

Tags: tables, spacing, width

I'm getting too much whitespaces and that makes values not maintain their alignment, spewing out into the margin. What do I need to do to fix this?

```
\documentclass[12pt,notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For better looking tables
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}                 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx}
 \usepackage{sub caption}
 \usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
 \newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro


  \begin{document}


  \begin{table}[ht!]   
\small
  \captionsetup{font={small,bf}}
  % We use 'tabular*' to auto-determine intercolumn whitespace:
   \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} 

  \caption{Descriptive statistics}

   \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}}d{1.0} d{1.0} *{4}{d{2.0}} d{1.0} d{1.0} *{5}{d{1.0}} }
    \multicolumn{5}{l}{Panel A. Sub-sample: Descriptive statistics} \\
  \toprule
    & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Before Covid-19 outbreak} & \multicolumn{7}{c}{After Covid-19 outbreak} 
  \\
      \cmidrule{2-7} \cmidrule{8-14} 
  & \mc{No of obs} & \mc{Mean} & \mc{Min} & \mc{Max} & \mc{Std.\ Dev.} & 
  & \mc{No of obs} & \mc{Mean} & \mc{Min} & \mc{Max} & \mc{Std.\ Dev} &  \\
 \midrule
Price & 2853 & 75.22 & 26.21 & 145.29 & 23.88 &  & 549 & 54.04 & -37.63 & 84.65 & 17.01   \\
Open  & 2853 & 75.25 & 27.30 & 145.19& 23.85 &  & 549 & 54.05 & -14.00 & 84.53 & 16.77   \\
High  & 2853 & 76.32 & 27.48 & 147.27& 24.01 &  & 549 & 55.10 & 13.69 & 85.41 & 16.54   \\
Low   & 2853 & 74.07 & 26.05 & 143.22 &23.66 &  & 549 & 52.91 & -40.32 & 83.39 & 17.21   \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\bigskip

 \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{8}{d{2.3}} *{2}{d{1.3}}}
\multicolumn{6}{l}{Panel B. Dickey-Fuller Test} \\
  \toprule
   & \mc{Test Statistic} & \mc{($p$-value)} & \mc{Lags} & \mc{No of obs} & \mc{ (1\%)} & \mc{ (5\%)} & \mc{(10\%)} & 
    \mc{D-type: float}   \\
    \midrule
     Price & 0.216 & (0.366) & 2853 & 0.094 & 0.865 & -0.234  & -0.164  &Yes \\
     \bottomrule
      \end{tabular*}

  \bigskip
  Here's a description for the table
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

My current ouput:

[image]

Comment: your main error here is the multicolumn(5) for the "Panel A" heading which is forcing the 5th column "Max" to be too wide to hold the spanning head. Note Werner changed that 5 to 11 as well as other changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code uses a regular `tabular`, setting the numeric elements via [`siunits`](//ctan.org/pkg/siunits)' `S`-column specification, rather than using [`dcolumn`](//ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn). With the standard `\tabcolsep`, the both `tabulars` fit within the margins you've specified

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs} % For better looking tables
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % handy shortcut macro

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \small
  \begingroup\centering
  \captionsetup{font={small,bf}}
  \caption{Descriptive statistics}
  %\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.5\tabcolsep}% Shrink \tabcolsep by 50%
  \begin{tabular}{
    l % Description
    % Before Covid-19 outbreak
    S[table-format=4.0] % No of obs
    S[table-format=2.2] % Mean
    S[table-format=2.2] % Min
    S[table-format=3.2] % Max
    S[table-format=2.2] % Std Dev
    % After Covid-19 outbreak
    S[table-format=3.0] % No of obs
    S[table-format=2.2] % Mean
    S[table-format=-2.2] % Min
    S[table-format=2.2] % Max
    S[table-format=2.2] % Std Dev
  }
    \multicolumn{11}{l}{Panel A. Sub-sample: Descriptive statistics} \\
    \toprule
      & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Before Covid-19 outbreak} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{After Covid-19 outbreak} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-11}
      & \mc{Obs} & \mc{Mean} & \mc{Min} & \mc{Max} & \mc{Std.\ Dev.} & 
        \mc{Obs} & \mc{Mean} & \mc{Min} & \mc{Max} & \mc{Std.\ Dev.} \\
    \midrule
    Price & 2853 & 75.22 & 26.21 & 145.29 & 23.88 & 549 & 54.04 & -37.63 & 84.65 & 17.01 \\
    Open  & 2853 & 75.25 & 27.30 & 145.19 & 23.85 & 549 & 54.05 & -14.00 & 84.53 & 16.77 \\
    High  & 2853 & 76.32 & 27.48 & 147.27 & 24.01 & 549 & 55.10 &  13.69 & 85.41 & 16.54 \\
    Low   & 2853 & 74.07 & 26.05 & 143.22 & 23.66 & 549 & 52.91 & -40.32 & 83.39 & 17.21 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}

  \bigskip

  \begin{tabular}{ l *{8}{c} }
    \multicolumn{9}{l}{Panel B. Dickey-Fuller Test} \\
    \toprule
    & \mc{Test Statistic} & \mc{($p$-value)} & \mc{Lags} & \mc{No of obs} & \mc{ (1\%)} & \mc{ (5\%)} & \mc{(10\%)} & \mc{D-type: float} \\
    \midrule
    Price & $0.216$ & $(0.366)$ & $2853$ & $0.094$ & $0.865$ & $-0.234$ & $-0.164$ & Yes \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  
  \bigskip
  \endgroup
  
  Here's a description for the table
\end{table}

\end{document}
```